# Mongodb version upgrade caused same queries to build up on queues

Tags: mongodb

Recently I upgraded one of our replicas from MongoDB version 2.4.3 to 2.6.3. It was a simple restart of the 3 mongodb replicas after upgrading of the binaries. After a few days, the same queries that were running for nearly a year on 2.4.3 started to build up causing very high load on the server. The load avg which used to be less than 1 all the time now spiked to over 300. Quick resolution was to failover and restart the mongod process which would bring the load down. But the new Primary would behave the same way in matter of a few hours and I would be forced to failover again and restart mongod. After a few such occurrences I downgraded the replicas to 2.4.10 and this seem to have resolved the load issue or queues building. Can anyone vouch for the theory to be true if you might have experienced a similar problem?

Comment: To answer this question, you have to give examples of the queries you are talking about - there were some changes in 2.6 that might have this type of effect (usually because 2.4 was doing something incorrectly) but without the query examples, it's just guess work

Comment: As Adam noted, there have been a number of changes in 2.6. It would be worth testing the latest 2.6.x production release (currently 2.6.7) as there have been many bug fixes and improvements since 2.6.3. See [Release Notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/) in the MongoDB manual for some highlighted issues and links to the full set of issues resolved in each point release.